# Saving RadioButtons locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, local-storage

I have a code of multiple radio buttons (nested in tabs) and I need to save and restore all values locally. I tried with cookies but only one value was saved. I tried with "localStorage" but I think I need some help. The basic idea is to save the values on each click and restore them on "window.onload".

If it is easier I can go back to cookies! Any experience anyone? Thank you in advance.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Saving RadioButtons locally</title>
    </head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">        </script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>

    <script src="scripts/modernizr.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //this function runs everytime there is a click from the mouse to update         and save the radio values (logicaly)
    function saveState() {
          //gets every object from the main form to read and save it.
              localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
            var data = $("#mainform").serializeArray();
            $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
              localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
            });
            console.log(data); //console shows only one object which is the first one (pid) with one value
        }


    //this function must be run each time the window loads to initialize the radio values (logicaly)
      function onloadfunction() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {
          //gets every object from the main form to read and restore it.
          var data = $("#mainform").serializeArray();
          $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            $("[name='" + obj.name +"']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
          });
        }
      }
      window.onload=onloadfunction;
      window.onbeforeunload=saveState;
    //end of ideas...............
    </script>


    <body>
    <form id="mainform" name='mainform'>

    <div id="container" class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Cid">Cid</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Bid">Bid</a></li>
    <!--  first tab  -->
    <!--  first radio box in first tab  -->
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Cid" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <form name='pid'>
      <input type="radio" id="p40" name="p" value="40">40
      <input type="radio" id="p45" name="p" value="45">45
      <input type="radio" id="p50" name="p" value="50">50
    </form>
    <!--   second radio box in first tab  -->
    <form name='BName'>
      <input type="radio" id="B40" name="B" value="40">40
      <input type="radio" id="B45" name="B" value="45">45
    </form>
        </div>
    <!--   second tab  -->
    <!--   first radio box in second tab  -->
    <div id="Bid" class="tab-pane fade">
    <form name='HName'>
      <input type="radio" id="H40" name="H" value="40">40
      <input type="radio" id="H45" name="H" value="45">45
      <input type="radio" id="H50" name="H" value="50">50
    </form>
        </div>


    </form>
    </body>
```